# First aid kit question suggestion

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

**The concensus appears to be that this is a not a good fit.**

---

Would *What items are good to have in your martial art club first aid kit box?* a question that would be good?

On one hand, it is not because it solicit both a list and oppinions.

On the other hand, there are lots of things that could be added to a first aid kit that are not obvious -- for example a card with the address (including GPS coordinates) of the dojo so when you have to call that ambulance, you *know* where to send them to do.

What do you think?

*How would you improve the question so that it is on topic?*

I do not mind it being a community wiki, I care very little about reputation.

Comment: How do you relate the first aid kit contents to martial arts specifically vs. any other sport?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what is so special about putting that in a martial arts context. Why would you need a card in your kit for your place of training? Wouldn't people there already know the physical address? What do first aid kits lack that martial arts would require short of calling an emergency line for an ambulance or taking someone to the hospital?

The question seems very open-ended and worded in a way that would solicit a list of items and opinions. I don't think it is very constructive in its current form. It just doesn't seem like a good question.

Comment: A card with your address allows you to *know* that whoever phones for the ambulance knows where you are.  Are you sure that *everyone* in your club can give detailed instructions over the phone while panicking?  If so, good for you.